# $scope not working in app.js file. But $scope works when HTML file has contents of app.js file

Tags: mysql, angularjs, rest, spring-boot, thymeleaf

When I use the Angular Script in HTML page Itself, all works fine including $scope.myOrderBy. But, when I use the same Script in Static/JS/app.js file everything is working except $scope.myOrderBy.
I want to use $scope.myOrderBy variable in app.js.

I found out that code actually works well in HTML itself but everything doesn't work in app.js file.

```
// app.js file

var app = angular.module("productManager", []);
app.controller("productController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.products = [];

    // This doesn't work and refelct back to html page.
    $scope.myOrderBy = "news";

    $scope.confirmDelete = false;
    $scope.productForm = {
        id: -1,
        proName: "",
        brand: "",
        madeIn: "",
        price: ""
    };

    _refreshProductData();

    function _refreshProductData() {
    }

    // Submit Button Button
    $scope.submitProduct = function () {

    };


    // Create New Product Button
    $scope.createNewProduct = function () {
    };


    // Delete Product Button
    $scope.deleteProduct = function (product) {
    };


    // Edit Product Button
    $scope.editProduct = function (product) {
    };

    // Success Function
    function _success(response) {
    };

    // Error Function
    function _error(response) {
    };

    // Clear Form Data
    function _clearFormData() {
    });
```

**Update 1:** Added HTML File:

```
<body ng-app = "productManager" ng-controller = "productController">
    <div align = "center">
        {{myOrder}}
        <h4>Product Manager : </h4>
        <form ng-submit = "submitProduct()">
            .
            .
            .
        </form>
        <button ng-click = "createNewProduct()">Create New Product</button>
    </div>
    <div align = "center">
        <h1>Product Catalogue : </h1>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" placeholder = "Enter Any" />
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    .
                    .

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat = "product in products | orderBy : myOrder>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    <td>
                        <button ng-click = "editProduct(product)">Edit</button>
                        <button ng-click = "deleteProduct(product)">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

**myOrderBy is the variable name in app.js file and you're using myOrder in HTML file.**
**Just change anyone with respect to other.**
Just a spelling error.

Comment: @Vinod Bokde Welcome. It's my pleasure.